# Why is the Hulk so different in the Hulk and the Agents of Smash cartoon series?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

In the new [Hulk and the Agents of Smash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_and_the_Agents_of_S.M.A.S.H.) cartoon, The Hulk spends most of each episode talking about his feelings and emotions, how he loves his friends and family and is so sad that everyone in the world thinks he's monster.

He even ends each episode by looking directly into the camera and saying:

> Hulk out.

His character and personality have changed so drastically from the Hulk most of us would know from the comics or movies.

What happened to him?

Comment: Why was this question closed? The answer is correct and NOT an opinion. While the OP question could use a bit of tightening up, this is a legitimate question. Perhaps we should fix the question rather than closing it.

Comment: @Thaddeus I've edited the final line of the question, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_and_the_Agents_of_S.M.A.S.H.):

> The story is told from the perspective of an online reality show created by Rick Jones to foster public acceptance of the Hulk as a hero and not a monster.

The [IMDB synopsis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2455514/) matches this.

> The Incredible Hulk teams up with Red Hulk, She-Hulk, Skaar, and Rick Jones aka A-Bomb to battle the forces of evil in front of cameras for Rick's web-based series to show the Hulk is more hero than monster.

What you're describing the episodes as is a pretty spot-on way to do this. Jones is attempting to humanize the Hulk, in an effort to raise public acceptance. By showing that the Hulk is **not** just a giant rage-monster, people will hopefully come to accept that he is not quite the dangerous threat to Earth that many believe him to be.

<sup>But he is.</sup>

Comment: Because, you know, it's really important that we all accept that these green giants are people too (in their own, hulking way) and have real feelings and we all need to be more sensitive to that. Or something like that.  Because how unfair would it be if we all went around with the pejorative mis-impression of the Hulk as a dangerous threat to planet Earth?